# Unable to call dropdown change method if dropdown value is fetched from Database

Tags: jquery

On Add and Edit form, I am calling jquery dropdown change method. It is working fine for Add form but I am unable to call change method if dropdown value is fetched from Database. Can we explictly trigger change method?

```
var stateid = '<?php echo $dbval['stateid']; ?>';

$("#stateid").change(function() {
        if(true == isEmpty($("#stateid").val())) {
            $("#stateid").focus();
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo  base_url(); ?>admin/health/loadCommonDataAjax/',
            data: {  dataType: 'state', dataVal: $("#stateid").val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(responseData) {

                if(responseData.result=='success') {
                    $("#districtid").empty().append("<option value=''>Select District First</option>");
                    var districtlength = responseData.districts.length;

                    for(var i=0; i<districtlength; i++) {
                        $("#districtid").append("<option value='"+responseData.districts[i].district_id+"'>"+responseData.districts[i].district_name+"</option>");
                    }   
                }
            },
            type: 'POST'
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#stateid").trigger("change");
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. Also I tried - $("#stateid").val(stateid).change(); Both ways are not working.

Comment: Yes, you must replace $("#stateid").change(function() {...}); with  $("#stateid").on("change", function() {...}); to works with trigger

Comment: I have made changes suggested by you but still not working. I am putting logs after trigger statment. It is also printing but not calling change method.

Comment: Trigger change is working fine if it is set on button click. But we get some value at time of document ready. Then it is not triggering event. $(document).ready(function() { If(someval) { $("#stateid").trigger("change"); } });

Comment: Try to fire trigger out of $(document).ready(), create new function with argument "someval" e.g. function fireChange(someval) { If(someval) { $("#stateid").trigger("change"); }